# MAUI Hybrid printout for Honeywell 6824

Tags: printing, maui-blazor, honeywell

I am trying to create an application in MAUI Hybrid and requirement is to do some print from application using Honeywell intermec 6824 printer. Got some sample code for web sdk but this is not working and giving response as blank that causing error. Please help me to achieve it